# Change selected item's layout in ListView (Custom Adapter)

Tags: java, android, listview

Is it possible to change layout of selected item in ListView?

I made simple app with ListView using Custom Adapter. It's working great, but I would like to change the layout of selected item to different layout.
In practice, the clicked item would expand it's height and some new buttons would appear. Once user deselects the items, it would go back to classic layout.

This is my Custom Adapter code

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Polozka> {

// context mem variable
private Context mContext;


// Konstruktory
public ListAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId){
    super(context,textViewResourceId);
}
public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Polozka> items){
    super(context,resource,items);
    this.mContext=context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;


    if (v == null){
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.polozkanakupniseznam,null);
    }

    final Polozka p = getItem(position);
    if (p != null){
        final TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.seznam_nazevPolozky);
        TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.seznam_pocetPolozky);
        CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_koupeno);
        Button btnPridat = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonPridat);
        Button btnOdebrat = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonOdebrat);

        if (tt1 != null){
            tt1.setText(p.getNazev());
        }

        if (tt2 != null){
            tt2.setText(Integer.toString(p.getPocet()));
        }

    return v;
}}
```

This is how I set adapter to my listview

```
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    adapter = new ListAdapter(this,R.layout.polozkaseznam,list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I figured out how to change layout of every item by creating new custom adapter and asigning it to the ListView, but that's sadly not what I need.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes it's possible. But it's better to use RecyclerView. And obviously you will never find a code exactly like yours. So you have to understand the other person code in order to apply the changes in your own.

Comment: I'll take a look at RecyclerView. I already found some article mentioning how to do it with RecyclerView in different post, but I wanted to ask if is there some easy way to do it with ListView also. :) Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The `getView()` method of the adapter is used to create the original view.  In there you can use the view's `setOnTouchListener()` method to add a [View.OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener) implementation.  The `onTouch()` handler of that class receives the selected view.

A useful member to add to the OnTouchListener implementation is a [GestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector); this is created with an OnGestureListener implementation to which you can pass the `MotionEvent` received in the OnTouchListener's `onTouch()` callback.  This listener is then used to distinguish various events (single tap, double tap, etc); [GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener) is good implementation to use with a number of callbacks handling such events you can override.

At some point (e.g., in the SimpleGestureListener's `onDown()` callback, which fires when an item is first touched), you can modify the layout of the view handed to the OnTouchListener.  To change it back, you could either use a handler for the "on up" phase of a gesture, or, if you wish the item to remain as is until something else is selected, hold a reference to the last selected view and change it when another one is selected.

In case this last point is not clear, the idea is that the SimpleGestureListener is a member object of the view's OnTouchListener instance, therefore it can access the view belonging to the enclosing OnTouchListener.

Comment: Why not to use the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try to figure it out.

Comment: `OnItemClickListener()` would be simpler if you just want to respond to someone tapping the element, as opposed to when the touch (finger down) occurs and release (finger up).